# Global flag in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
function countSmileys(arr) {
    let regex = /^([:;])([-~])*([)D])$/
    if(arr.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return arr.filter(el => {
        return regex.test(el);
    })
}

console.log(countSmileys([':(', ';)', ':)', ';o>', ':(', ':>', ';~D']));
```

I wrote the code that verify to see if that is smiley face or not.
for eyes, it takes only ':/;' , for nose, '-/~' (it is fine if there is a nose)
for lips, ')/D'.

So, I wrote the regular expression with global flag first. then
it only gives

```
[';)', ';~D']
```

I finally got the right result when I eliminated g flag.

```
[';)', ':)', ';~D']
```

I have been confused to use g flags. can anyone explain this?

Comment: running a regex with the global flag on a string advances the regex's `lastIndex`. Reusing the regex will then not start at the first letter, but actually at the index after the match in the last string.

Comment: In the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag

Comment: @ASDFGerte terrific comment. Could you please link some documentation, so that I for one can add it to my bookmarks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results)

Comment: the MDN article epascarello linked details pretty much the same thing, if you need something to bookmark. There is also some documentation about regex's `lastIndex` in the articles for `exec`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks, yes I also found another question here on SO with an excellent explaination

Comment: Thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is using `test()` with the global flag on a string advances the regex's `lastIndex` - even if you are testing a different string in a subsequent run.

Citing from the MDN: [Using `test()` on a regex with the global flag](http://Using%20test()%20on%20a%20regex%20with%20the%20global%20flag%20%20If%20the%20regex%20has%20the%20global%20flag%20set,%20test()%20will%20advance%20the%20lastIndex%20of%20the%20regex.%20A%20subsequent%20use%20of%20test()%20will%20start%20the%20search%20at%20the%20substring%20of%20str%20specified%20by%20lastIndex%20(exec()%20will%20also%20advance%20the%20lastIndex%20property).%20It%20is%20worth%20noting%20that%20the%20lastIndex%20will%20not%20reset%20when%20testing%20a%20different%20string.)

> If the regex has the global flag set, `test()` will advance the 
>   `lastIndex` of the regex. 
>    A subsequent use of `test()` search at the substring of `str` specified by `lastIndex` (`exec()` will also advance the lastIndex property). 
>   It is worth noting that the lastIndex will not reset when testing a different string.

Comment: Pretty much everything was already said in the comment but let's settle the case.

Comment: Thanks for help!